# How to find End of File in Python

Tags: python

In python I am facing a strange situation - I am reading it character by charecter and can not determine the End of File. Can you please help me out?

Comment: What are you reading? A file?

Comment: Yes a file I am reading it using <FileName>.read(1) so that it reads each character but I am failing to identify the End Of File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of a file is indicated when the `read()` returns less data than you asked for.